# Lua not producing table of functions (IO API)

Tags: file-io, lua, lua-table

I'm working on a basic project in Lua. I've been trying to get data from files using the `IO` API (as defined [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.7)), but when I open a file and give it a handle, it doesn't seem to return a table of functions.

The (erroneous bit of) code:

```
local unread = fs.list("email/"..from.."/")
local send = ""
for _,file in ipairs(unread) do
    local handle = io.open(file,"r")
    local text = handle:read("*a")
    send = send .. text .. "\n"
    handle.close()
    fs.delete(file)
end
```

The `fs` you see on the first line is a professional filesystem wrapper round the IO API, not my work and perfectly error-free, so that's not the problem. However, when I try to read the file (`handle:read()`), it throws "attempt to index nil". Tracing it, it turns out that `handle` itself is `nil`. Any ideas?

Comment: try `print( file )` to see if it is only the filename or the entire path to file.

Comment: As @hjpotter92 indicates if `file` is a valid path then `handle` should be non-nil assuming you have permissions to read the file. If the path is incorrect, or incomplete (e.g. relative to the path given in the `fs.list` call) then you need to either fix the `fs` library or construct the right absolute or relative path before trying to open the file.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Liking that idea, I'll have a look at it. I thought I had the right path but didn't realise it could screw it up so much if I did have it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `io.open` returns a file handle on success, and nil with error message on failure (as per Lua reference manual). This means that really you should use

```
handle, err = io.open(file, 'r')
if handle == nil then 
    print('could not open file:', file, ':', err)
    return
end
local text = handle:read("*a")
...
```

The error message will tell you if you don't have permission to read the file, or if there is some other issue.